# iOS: Auto-incremental NSString

Tags: ios, string, integer, coordinate

I'm in the process of refactoring my app that shows a bunch of polygons and annotations on a map view.

At the moment it's quite literally a case of a lot of code that consists of elements such as these:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate1;
theCoordinate1.latitude = xx.xxxxx;
theCoordinate1.longitude = x.xxxxx;

MyAnnotation* myAnnotation1=[[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
myAnnotation1.coordinate=theCoordinate1;
myAnnotation1.title=@"buildingTitle";
myAnnotation1.subtitle=@"BuildingAddress";
```

I then add the annotations to the mapview. However with multiple annotations this results in a lot of code and I'm looking at being a bit smarter here by loading the coordinates from a text file into a method that consists of a for loop (so the same block of code will define the coordinates and create the annotation from those coordinates).

The only issue in my way at the moment is how to give the annotations different names. If I'm initialising an annotation object it has to surely have a different name from the previous one? I'm okay with them simply having numeric suffixes, so how would I go about doing this?
Could I add code to autoincrement an NSInteger and then convert it to NSString and append?

Answer (score 1):

> If I'm initialising an annotation object it has to surely have a
>   different name from the previous one?

Not really. Assuming you do all of your annotation inside of your loop you can use the same name for the variable, it won't cause any problems because the scope of that variable is confined within the loop.

If you need to access/find the objects later then you will want to do is store those annotations in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can easily add a number to a string:

```
int increment = 0;
// etc....
NSString *myLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myLabel-%d", increment++];
```